# Configure API event integration as "lambda" instead of default "lambda proxy" in AWS SAM Template

Tags: aws-serverless, aws-sam

All the examples of SAM use Events for Serverless::functions in default state mostly. And by default, the API integration for a Lambda is configured to be "Lambda proxy".

I require integration type "Lambda (non-proxy)" with the following setting in "Mapping"
[image]

How can I achieve that using SAM templates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want more control over your API (e.g., to bypass certain defaults/assumptions that AWS SAM makes), you should explicitly define your [`AWS::Serverless::Api`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-resource-api.html) and pass along the definition of the API using the OpenAPI specification (either using the `DefinitionUri` or `DefinitionBody` attributes). In the specification, you have more control over how the API should integrate with the lambda functions. Setting the [type attribute on the `x-amazon-apigateway-integration` object](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-swagger-extensions-integration.html) will allow you to use the `aws` integration instead of the `aws_proxy` integration.

You should still either configure the `Events` section in the lambda function or manually fix the necessary permissions in order to ensure that your API Gateway will have permission to invoke the lambda.