# AWS Serverless Transform API Gateway Deployment Issues

Tags: amazon-web-services, rest, aws-lambda, aws-serverless

Thanks for any help in advance.

I am trying to deploy a RestAPI to AWS using API Gateway, Lambda Functions and Cognito Authorizers. I am using the AWS Extension for Visual Studio, through this I am using the AWS Serverless Application project and using the ASP.NET API template. I added a AWS::Serverless::API to the default serverless.template to allow me to add a Cognito Authorizer. This has had the effect of defaulting all my endpoints to 'Use Lambda Proxy Intergration' which results in all my endpoints returning "Internal Server Error" no matter the input.

From this: [Configure API event integration as "lambda" instead of default "lambda proxy" in AWS SAM Template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69397312/configure-api-event-integration-as-lambda-instead-of-default-lambda-proxy-in)
I understand that I need to add a OpenAPI defintion to my serverless.template to make the 'type', 'aws' not 'aws_proxy'. I however cannot get this to work.

Here is my serverless.template so far:

```json
{
    "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
    "Transform": "AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31",
    "Description": "An AWS Serverless Application that uses the ASP.NET Core framework running in Amazon Lambda.",
    "Parameters": {},
    "Conditions": {},
    "Resources": {
      "MyAPI" : {
              "Type" : "AWS::Serverless::Api",
              "Properties" : {
                  "StageName" : "Prod",
                  "Auth" : {
                      "DefaultAuthorizer" : "MyAuth",
                      "Authorizers" : {
                          "MyAuth" : {
                              "UserPoolArn" : "arn:aws:cognito-idp:<region>:<arn>:userpool/<user_pool_arn>",
                              "Identity" : {
                                  "Header" : "Authorization"
                              },
                              "AuthType" : "COGNITO_USER_POOLS"
                          }
                      }
                  }
              }
          },
      "AspNetCoreFunction": {
        "Type": "AWS::Serverless::Function",
        "Properties": {
          "Handler": "AspTest::AspTest.LambdaEntryPoint::FunctionHandlerAsync",
          "Runtime": "dotnet6",
          "CodeUri": "",
          "MemorySize": 256,
          "Timeout": 30,
          "Role": null,
          "Policies": [
            "AWSLambda_FullAccess"
          ],
          "Events": {
            "ProxyResource": {
              "Type": "Api",
              "Properties": {
                "Path": "/{proxy+}",
                "Method": "ANY",
                "RestApiId" : "MyAPI",
                "Auth" : {
                  "Authorizer" : "MyAuth"
                }
              }
            },
            "RootResource": {
              "Type": "Api",
              "Properties": {
                "Path": "/",
                "Method": "ANY",
                "RestApiId" : "MyAPI",
                "Auth" : {
                  "Authorizer" : "MyAuth"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```